# Storing data in a JTable from linked lists

Tags: java, swing, data-structures, linked-list, jtable

I'm writing a program in Java where I write my own data structure like this:

```
public void putInList(Object newobject) {
    Object pointer = first;
    if (first == null) {
        first = newobject;
    } else { 
        while ( pointer.next != null ) 
            pointer = pointer.next; 
        pointer.next = newobject;
    }
}
```

The Object class contains some variables with values.

Is it possible to get a JTable to read the values and store it in the table? How can I do this?

Comment: This official tutorial will help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: Reimplementing a LinkedList instead of using the standard one in the JDK is not a very goodidea. And using a LinkedList to back a JTable is not a good idea either, because JTable accesses its model by row index. Using an ArrayList is a much better idea. For the rest, read the JTable tutorial and implement an AbstractTableModel.

Comment: "The Object class contains some variables with values" are you hiding the `java.lang.Object` class? If so, this is a Bad Idea. Try using a generic type instead.

Comment: You should also have a reference to the last item on the list, making it faster to append items

Comment: Write your own TableModel and get its getValueAt() method to return items in your linked list.